# Same image on same table, one is centered the other not

Tags: latex

As you can see here, same picture insert (Apple logo) on this table, but result is different.
[image]

here is the code :

```
\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec={Q[valign=b]Q[valign=b]Q[valign=h]},
  row{1}={halign=c},
  row{2}= {halign=C},
row{3}= {halign=C},
  vlines,
  hlines
}
\textbf{Id} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Figure} \\
1   & Press an imaginary button & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{gesture/Button1.png}\\ \hline
2   & Double press an imaginary button & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{gesture/test.png}\\ \hline
3   & Close the fist & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{gesture/closeFist.PNG} \\ \hline
4   & Open the fist & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{gesture/openFist.PNG}  \\ \hline
5   & Touch the ring & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{gesture/test.PNG} \\ \hline
6   & Touch 2 times the ring & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/touchRing2.PNG} \\ \hline
\end{longtblr}
```

I would like to center all the picture of the tab, if somoene have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
row{2}= {halign=C},
row{3}= {halign=C},
```

you are only centring the rows with ID 1 and 2. If you also want all the other images centred, change the `halign` of the entire column instead of doing this for individual rows.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec={Q[valign=b]Q[valign=b]Q[valign=h,halign=C]},
  row{1}={halign=c},
%  row{2}= {halign=C},
%  row{3}= {halign=C},
  vlines,
  hlines
}
\textbf{Id} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Figure} \\
1   & Press an imaginary button & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{example-image-duck}\\ \hline
2   & Double press an imaginary button & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-duck}\\ \hline
3   & Close the fist & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-duck} \\ \hline
4   & Open the fist & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-duck}  \\ \hline
5   & Touch the ring & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-duck} \\ \hline
6   & Touch 2 times the ring & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-duck} \\ \hline
\end{longtblr}


\end{document}
```

[image]